# Debian on SSD not recognised after installing Windows 10

Tags: linux, debian, ssd, boot-partition

Due to school-related reasons I am required to have Windows; I got it installed but my issue now is that my BIOS only recognizes the Windows HDD and not my Debian SSD. Is there any way to fix this without reinstalling Debian?
(MB: MSI H170 GAMING M3 (MS-7978) G216435578 2.0)
(OS: Debian 9 kinda, Windows 10)

Comment: How are the HDs connected? Did the BIOS detect both HDs before the installation?

Comment: You had Debian installed first, then installed Windows? Does the BIOS not see the SSD, or does it not show it as a boot option?

Comment: The Bios detected the SSD with Debian installed before.

Comment: The right way to indicate you have solved your problem by yourself is posting an answer and accepting it. Please take our short [tour] to learn how the site works.

Comment: This is also relevant: [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) The bare link you tried to include in your answer is not enough though; please note [link-only answers are low quality](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer).